# S3 list access based on IP restriction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, amazon-iam

In Amazon S3, can we specify list access only to those anonymous users who satisfy the IP restriction policy?

AFAIK, giving list access means anyone from internet can access that bucket. But use case here is to limit that set of anonymous users based on the IPs.

**Bucket Policy :**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "123Sample",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::exampleBucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "x.x.x.x/a"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can.  Perhaps you'd be kind enough to show your current bucket policy?  Sanitize as appropriate, but with caution to not break the format.  Or mention mention that you're not using a bucket policy, if you aren't.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot updated.